# Why are my jalapeño peppers wilting suddenly just at the very tips of the fruit?

Tags: diagnosis, peppers, wilt

Why are my jalapeño peppers suddenly  wilting at the tips of the fruit?

Comment: Can you share a picture please?

Comment: Welcome! When you add your pictures, would you also please tell us some more things, like: where you live; what the temperatures are like right now; what kind of watering schedule they're on; how old the peppers are; if you've had this happen before; if you've seen any bugs; other things like that. I know that's a lot of questions! We just want to get a better sense of what's happening so we can be the most help! Since you're new, check out our [help] to see how the site works, and if you have questions about anything, don't hesitate to ask!

Answer (score 3):

Pictures would help on this, but the fruit tips showing distress is often an incipient indicator of blossom end rot in tomatoes, peppers and similar vegetable fruits is often a sign that there isn't enough free calcium available in their growing medium during the fruit growth.

Things that can mess up the calcium availability are:

1. not enough calcium in the soil
2. excessive watering
3. allowing the soil to dry out, followed by a good overwatering
4. over-fertilizing with nitrogen products or excess sodium/potassium